# Scapy documentation uses confusing code for a function

Tags: python

I've been having fun with Scapy. While reading the documentation, it explains how to show the important information of a port-scan reply with "a simple loop", which goes like this:

```
ans.summary( lambda(s,r): r.sprintf("%TCP.sport% \t %TCP.flags%") )
```

I can sort of understand what lambda does, however what trips me up is everything after lambda. I assume (s,r) is mapping s and r to the "send" and "received" packets of the tuple returned by ans.summary. I've been looking around for sprintf, and can't find anything pertaining to python about it. I also assume that %TCP.sport% is a scapy specific format string.

What does it all mean and how does it work?

Comment: line 1063: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/40d62678b70480387395876c2efdb6f4f2a944f0/scapy/packet.py  always read the source code ...

Comment: This helps! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ans.summary()` accepts a function as a parameter that will be used to represent each (sent packed, received response) tuple.

If no function is specified, something equivalent to `lambda s, r: "%s ==> %s" % (s.summary(), r.summary())` is used.

The function must accept to arguments (the sent packet and the corresponding received answer), and return a string.

In your case, the function is `lambda(s, r): r.sprintf("%TCP.sport% \t %TCP.flags%")`. It only uses the second parameter (the answer), and calls `.sprintf()`, which is a method defined of Scapy `Packet` objects (that's not a Python standard, but something specific to these objects). The formatting elements in `.sprintf()` are related to layers and field values. Here, the call will return a string containing the TCP source port (from the answer packet) followed by "space tab space" and the TCP flags.

If you apply this to `sr()` result for a TCP scan, this will hence show each scanned port with "SA" if the port is open and "RA" if it is closed.